# How to prove that $A$ surjective $\iff \ker (A^*) = \{0\}$ and $\operatorname{Im}(A^*)$ is closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $A$ be a linear densely defined closed operator on a Hilbert space $A: D(A) \subseteq H \to H$. I have to show that $A$ surjective $\iff \ker (A^*) = \{0\}$ and  $\operatorname{Im}(A^*)$ is closed. I know that $\operatorname{Im}(A)$ is closed $\iff \operatorname{Im}(A)=\ker(A^*)^\perp$. So I know that if $A$ is surjective, then $A^*$ is injective. However, I don't know how to prove the rest. Any hints ?

Comment: I take it that $A$ is an operator on a Hilbert space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is surjective. Lets show that the image of $A^*$ is closed.

Let $x_n\in D(A^*)$ so that $A^*x_n$ converges to some $y$. Then for all $z\in H$ there is some $z'\in D(A)$ with $z= Az'$ and:
$$\langle x_n, z\rangle =  \langle A^*x_n ,z'\rangle \to \langle y, z'\rangle$$
It follows that $\langle x_n, z\rangle$ is bounded as $n\to\infty$. Since $z$ is arbitrary uniform boundedness shows that $x_n$ is a bounded sequence. By passing to a subsequence assume that $x_n$ converges weakly to some $x\in H$. Then for all $z\in D(A)$:

$$\langle x, A z\rangle = \lim_n \langle x_n, Az\rangle=\lim_n\langle A^*x_n,z\rangle = \langle y, z\rangle$$
and $x\in D(A^*)$ with $A^*x=y$. This shows the image is closed.

---

Now suppose that $\ker(A^*)=0$ and the image of $A^*$ is closed. A standard calculation shows that $\ker(A^*)=0$ implies that the image of $A$ is dense.

Let $x_n\in D(A)$ so that $Ax_n$ converges to some $y$. Since $\mathrm{Im}(A^*)$ is closed let $p$ be the projection to this subspace. One has for all $z\in D(A^*)$:
$$\langle Ax_n,z\rangle=\langle x_n, A^*z\rangle = \langle px_n, A^*z\rangle$$
and so $px_n\in D(A^{**})=D(A)$ (since $A$ is closed). Additionally $px_n$ is bounded since for all $z\in H$ you have a $z'\in D(A^*)$ so that
$$\langle p x_n, z\rangle = \langle x_n, pz\rangle = \langle x_n, A^* z'\rangle\to \langle x, z'\rangle$$
and you apply uniform boundedness as above. Then there is a weak limit $x$ of $px_n$ and for all $z\in D(A^*)$:
$$\langle x, A^*z\rangle = \lim_n\langle px_n,A^*z\rangle =\lim_n \langle x_n A^*z\rangle =\lim_n \langle Ax_n,z\rangle=\langle y,x_n\rangle$$
and so $x\in D(A^{**})=D(A)$ (since $A$ is closed) and $Ax =A^{**}x=y$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In both parts, how can you pass to a weakly converging subsequence without assuming reflexivity of the Hilbert space ?

Comment: Also, is the statement $A^{**}=A$ for closed operators an easy lemma or does it rely on a nontrivial theorem ?

Comment: See https://loss.math.gatech.edu/17SPRINGTEA/7334/NOTES/section3closedoperators.pdf (Theorem 0.9) for a proof about $A^{**}=A$ iff $A$ closed. About reflexivity: Hilbert spaces are always reflexive! This is a consequence of Riesz